# How to make arduino communicate between 2 devices using RS232 serial port?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm new in Arduino.
I have some medical devices that send and receive data using RS232 (DB9) serial port communication to and from the computer. Some other devices send and receive data between each other. However , some devices from different manufacturers need some formatting modification for data before being received from other devices. I used to do this through the computer to receive data from device 1 then modify formatting then resend to device 2 and this did the job, but this requires one computer between 2 devices. I'm asking if Arduino is able to do the job by connecting to 2 devices at the same time using serial port (DB9) so it can receive data from first device and resend it to another device after little modification in formatting using code. I know it is not straightforward but if it is possible even in a hard way , i would appreciate if somebody guided me how to do that. Thank you

Comment: yes this is possible. an answer to this can be obtained through simple web search. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialPassthrough  all you need to do is to add the formatting. you can also use the SoftwareSerial library if you do not have two hardware usarts. if oyu only receive with one and send to another it should even be sufficient to use 1 USART

Comment: If you want to read into this topic online (free): https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/arduino-cookbook/9781449399368/ch04.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one-way forwarding this is sufficient. Feel free to add your formatting.

```
Serial.write(Serial.read());
```

Of course this needs to be embedded in a valid Arduino sketch.

If you want to forward in both directions you'll need a second hardware USART or emulate that on digital I/Os using the SoftwareSerial library for example.

Comment: Thank you, I already searched a lot , but i want to ask for specific details. I will receive only from one device that has only DB9 and send only to one device that also use DB8. I figured out that i should connect one device using max232 chip to one device and send data using Rx and Tx pins. How could i receive from the first device ?

Comment: @EgyEast max232 is just a level shifter that brings the Arduino's 5 or 3.3v logic to the RS232 level. if your communication is one way you hook up the max232 to the Arduino's Rx and Tx pins. then you hook up the sending devices Tx pin to the Max232's Rx and the receiving devices Rx to the Max232's Tx pin. all have to share the same GND.  incoming data is received by the arduino, formatted and forwarded to the receiving device. just do any Arduino Serial tutorial and don't hook up your Arduino to the devices without level shifting.

Comment: Thank's alot for your help